# jquery multiple input fields with class="decimal" If in one field typed dot, then can not type dot in another field

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/429efu08/

Multiple input fields.

For each field want not to allow type more than one `.` or `,` (not to allow `..`, `.,`, `,.,.`)

Problem is because of `decimal_exists`. Before function i define `decimal_exists == false`

Then function starts to work. If either `.` or `,` typed, then `decimal_exists == true` and it remains true. So if i try to type `.` or `,` in another input field because of `decimal_exists == true` i can not type.

One solution is create/repeat the same function for each `id`. But better only one function for `class`.

Some another solution would be to create hidden input field near each input field with `class="decimal"` and check value of the input field.

But is it possible instead of `decimal_exists` define some variable for each input field and check value of the variable? If yes, then how?

Here is jquery code

```
var decimal_exists = false;
$(document).on("keydown", ".decimal", function(e){

    if( ($(this).val().indexOf(',')) != -1 && ($(this).val().indexOf('.')) != -1 ){
        decimal_exists = false;
    }

    if( ( ($(this).val().indexOf(',')) != -1 || decimal_exists == true ) && e.keyCode == 188 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if( ( ($(this).val().indexOf('.')) != -1 || decimal_exists == true ) && e.keyCode == 190 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if( ($(this).val().indexOf(',')) != -1 || ($(this).val().indexOf('.')) != -1 ){
        decimal_exists = true;
    }

    if (
        e.which != 8 && 
        e.which != 9 && 
        e.which != 0 && 
        e.which != 37 && 
        e.which != 39 && 
        e.which != 44 && 
        e.which != 46 && 
        e.which != 190 && 
        e.which != 188 && 
        (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && 
        (e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)
    ) {
          $(this).next(".errmsg").html("Numbers Only");
          $(this).css("border", "solid 1px red");
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
          $(this).next(".errmsg").html("");
          $(this).css("border", "");
      }

      $(this).val( this.value.replace(/,/g, ".") );
});
```

**Solution**

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".decimal", function(e){

if( ($(this).val().indexOf(',')) != -1 && ( e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 190 ) ){
e.preventDefault();
}

if( ($(this).val().indexOf('.')) != -1 && ( e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 190 ) ){
e.preventDefault();
}

if (
e.which != 8 && 
e.which != 9 && 
e.which != 0 && 
e.which != 37 && 
e.which != 39 && 
e.which != 44 && 
e.which != 46 && 
e.which != 190 && 
e.which != 188 && 
(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && 
(e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)
) {
$(this).next(".errmsg").html("Numbers Only");
$(this).css("border", "solid 1px red");
e.preventDefault();
}
else{
$(this).next(".errmsg").html("");
$(this).css("border", "");
}

});
```

Comment: It is because you are using a global variable... I think in this scenario it will be better to check whether the value contains a `.` than using a variable to store the state

Comment: If you continue to use the same logic checkout the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) api to store the state of each element